# How to recognise intuitively which functions grow faster asymptotically?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, logarithms, asymptotics

There are some cases where it is not so simple to decide which function grows faster asymptotically.

For example, in the following cases, why (intuitively) $g(n)$ should grow faster than $f(n)$, or vice-versa?

### $$
\begin{array}{c|c}
f(n) & g(n)\\
\hline
10 \log(n) & \log(n^2)\\
\frac{n^2}{\log(n)} & n(\log(n))^2\\
n^{0.1} & \log(n)^{10}\\
\log(n)^{\log(n)} & \frac{n}{\log(n)}\\
\sqrt n & \log(n)^3\\
n\,2^n & 3^n\\
\log(n)^{\log(n)} & 2^{(\log_2 n)^2}
\end{array}
$$

It is easy to type some values on a calculator or to plot the functions to see which one grows faster, but during an exam I cannot do this of course.

Comment: Another helpful rule of thumb: $n^k$ grows faster than $\log(n)^l$ for any fixed positive exponents $k,l$.

Comment: @KlausDraeger This is not really a rule of thumb, because it holds in any case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ultimately, it suffices to evaluate the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(n)}{f(n)}
$$
if it's $\infty$, then $g$ grows faster.  If it's $0$, then $f$ grows faster.  If it's anything else, then they grow the same (up to some constant), i.e. $f = \Theta(g)$.

As far as intuition goes, it helps to rewrite things, or sometimes to divide/multiply both sides by the same term.

1. Rewrite $\log(n^2) = 2 \log(n)$.  It should now be obvious.
2. Divide both sides by $\frac{n}{\log(n)}$.  We're now comparing $n$ to $\log(n)^3$. $n$ is asymptotically larger since $n^\alpha$ will always beat $\log(n)^\beta$ for any $\alpha,\beta > 0$ ("polynomial beats log").  Similarly, $e^{n^\alpha}$ will always beat $n^\beta$ for any $\alpha,\beta > 0$ ("exponential beats polynomial").
3. Same rule as last time.  The left side is larger.
4. Rewrite $\log(n)^{\log(n)} = n^{\log(\log(n))}$ (how?).  Perhaps it is now clear that the left side beats $n$, let alone $\frac{n}{\log(n)}$.
5. Polynomial always beats log (see 2.). Left is larger.
6. Divide both sides by $2^n$. Now, the right side is larger because exponential always beats polynomial (see 2.). Right is larger.
7. Rewrite the right side as $n^{\log_2(n)}$ (how?). This beats $n^{\log(\log(n))}$ (why)? So, the right side is larger.

---

Note on 4: we have
$$
\log(n)^{\log(n)} = [e^{\log(\log(n))}]^{\log(n)} = 
e^{\log(n)\log(\log(n))} = 
[e^{\log(n)}]^{\log(\log(n))} = n^{\log(\log(n))}
$$

Comment: @nbro: $\tfrac{3^n}{2^n}=\left(\tfrac{3}{2}\right)^n$

Answer (score 1):

You can use known limits such has $\lim _{n\to \infty} \frac {k^n}{n^h}=\infty \quad \forall k>1$ and $h\in \mathbb{R}$ or $\lim _{n\to \infty} \frac {n^h}{\log^k{n}}=\infty \quad \forall k> O,h\in \mathbb{R}$. For example if you compute $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ from the second line you obtain $\frac{n}{\log^3{n}}$ which has infinite as limit so $f(n)$ grows faster.