# how to tell which function asymptotically grows faster than other?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

[I read this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382947/how-to-recognise-intuitively-which-functions-grow-faster-asymptotically)

But functions in my case seems to be complicated to me..

---

Which of the following functions asymptotically grows the fastest as $n$ goes to infinity?

$(\log \log(n))!$

$(\log\log(n))^{\log(n)}$

$(\log\log(n))^{\log\log\log(n)}$

$(\log(n))^{\log\log(n)}$

$2^{\sqrt{\log\log(n)}}$

---

for example take the first and second function that are

$f(n) = (\log\log(n))!$

$g(n) = (\log\log(n))^{\log(n)}$

now calculating

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$

$f(n)$ it's derivative can't be calculated.

Then how can I tell which function asymptotically grows fastest ?

The answer given in the book is $(\log\log(n))^{\log(n)}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Your formatting will look nicer if you write \log instead of log.  (Same goes for \sin, \max, etc.)

Comment: I suppose the first is $f(n)=\log\bigl(\log(n!)\bigr)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take logarithms.  To compare the second with the first, for example,  ee have $$
\log((\log\log n)^{\log n}) = \log n \cdot\log\log\log n \tag{1}$$
On the other hand, we know that $\log(x!) \sim x\log x,$ so that $$
\log(\log \log n)!) \sim \log\log n \cdot \log\log\log n\tag{2} $$
Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that $(1)$ grows much faster.

It looks to me like the fourth one is the biggest, just doing it in my head.

Comment: What is $\log(x!)$ if $x$ is not a positive integer?

Comment: @Bernard I assume he's talking about the gamma function

Comment: @saulspatz use of stirling approximation was a nice idea.